# Implicit interface inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I am just wondering which of this two methods, bool IsReal() from IFirstInterface or ISecondInterface, we are actually using in ExampleClass now:

```
interface IFirstInterface
{
    bool IsReal(); 
}
interface ISecondInterface
{
    bool IsReal();
}



public class ExampleClass : IFirstInterface, ISecondInterface
{
    public bool IsReal() {}
    //public bool IsReal is IFirstInterface or ISecondInterface method.
}
```

Please, could someone explain me how Implicit interface really works in C#.

Comment: It is providing an implementation for both methods.

Comment: @YacoubMassad how can i be sure about that?

Comment: The compiler wouldn't be happy if any of interfaces didn't have all their methods implemented.

Comment: @YacoubMassad sure,I forgot about that.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Explicit [Interface Implementation guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) you can read the following statement:

> If a class implements two interfaces that contain a member with the
>   same signature, then implementing that member on the class will cause
>   both interfaces to use that member as their implementation.

You can implement one or both interfaces explicitly to override this behavior:

```
interface IFirstInterface
{
    bool IsReal(); 
}
interface ISecondInterface
{
    bool IsReal();
}

public class ExampleClass : IFirstInterface, ISecondInterface
{
    // will be used for IFirstInterface
    bool IFirstInterface.IsReal(){}

    // will be used for ISecondInterface
    public bool IsReal(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarity purposes you should implement both functions
public bool IFirstInterface.IsReal() {}
public bool ISecondInterface.IsReal() {}

Comment: Than it will be Explicit interface inheritance as I know.